# Return array and show without iterating in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am sending array through the controller in compact.

```
    $medicines = Medicine::all()->pluck('medicine_name')->toArray();
    return view('orders.order',compact('medicines'));
```

I want to display array in the blade without iterating,

output should be like $medicines = ['medicine1','medicine2','medicine3']

how to achieve it?

if I return $medicine variable I am getting the expected output how do I pass into the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implode the result first then assign that

```
$medicines = Medicine::all()->pluck('medicine_name')->toArray();
$medicines = implode(",",$medicines);
return view('orders.order',compact('medicines'));
```

in your view add this code

```
{{ $medicines}}
```

Comment: I don't want to iterate the array. I just want to print array

Answer (score 0):

If you want just output you can try as

```
<?php echo "\$medicines = ['".implode("','",$medicines)."']"; ?>
```

Here is Live demo : https://eval.in/915767

Comment: but the output here is collection of array. i want simple array. try returning medicine variable it will simply return array i want that output in view

Comment: @iamsujit : If you want just output you can try as updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding you...

you can use json_encode to "convert" the array to string and then print it ... ( use the {!!} to print and not {{}} )

in the tempalte add this:

```
$medicines = '{! json_encode($medicines) !}'
```

you can event use implode if you want ...

```
@php echo '$medicines = '[\''.imlode("', '", $medicines).'\']' @endphp
```